# Mesh on the Umbilic torus

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, mesh

There is a $3D$ graphic of the [Umbilic torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbilic_torus).

```
x[u_, v_] := Sin[u] (7 + Cos[u/3 - 2 v] + 2 Cos[u/3 + v])
y[u_, v_] := Cos[u] (7 + Cos[u/3 - 2 v] + 2 Cos[u/3 + v])
z[u_, v_] := Sin[u/3 - 2 v] + 2 Sin[u/3 + v]

ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}, {u, -Pi, Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, 
PlotPoints -> 150, MaxRecursion -> 3, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> 36]
```

but there is a gap on the mesh

[image]

How can I make a mesh like [this](http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/larson/calculus_analytic/7e/instructors/downloads/lab19mta.pdf)?

[image]

Comment: It depends on what you would like to do: Would this help you: `mr = DiscretizeRegion[
   ParametricRegion[{x[u, v], y[u, v], 
     z[u, v]}, {{u, -Pi, Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}}]];
HighlightMesh[mr, {2}]`

Comment: That mesh irregularity seems to be inherent in the parametric equations you used; the situation is similar to that of the Möbius strip. To see this for yourself, add the settings `Mesh -> {Subdivide[-π, π, 8]}, MeshFunctions -> {#5 &}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameterization is all fine. It is just that you need a number of rectangles in the `v`-direction that is divisable by `3`. The issue here is that `Mesh` counts only the *interior* mesh lines, so that the value of `Mesh` needs to be *smaller by 1* than the number of desired reactangles.

```
x[u_, v_] := Sin[u] (7 + Cos[u/3 - 2 v] + 2 Cos[u/3 + v])
y[u_, v_] := Cos[u] (7 + Cos[u/3 - 2 v] + 2 Cos[u/3 + v])
z[u_, v_] := Sin[u/3 - 2 v] + 2 Sin[u/3 + v]

ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotPoints -> {149, 149},
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
 Mesh -> {35, 35},
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 4}
 ]
```

[image]